# MySQL Concat or Fetch and Merge with PHP; Which one is cheaper for server?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a character to a particular field in my table, withouth touching the old data.

For example my table will contain XXX and I want to add one more X.

I need to do this to a large group of tables, so I'm looking for the proper method.

Either I will use `mysql_fetch_array()` function, get the string and will put my extra character using PHP. Then I'll update the table. Or, I will use concat in SQL directly.

I need to know which one is cheaper for the server. Also I would be happy to hear any more suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Its better to use `concat` within **MySQL** query instead to `concat` it within **PHP** side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query will be cheaper because you won't have the overhead of running PHP and will be running it directly against the data all at once.  How to update:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET someColumn=CONCAT(someColumn,'X');
```

With your proposed PHP method you would need to update each row individually where as a query will update all at once.  All those update queries add up and will be more taxing on the server.